# create new record into DB using java RESTful web service

Tags: java, web-services, ibm-cloud

Here's my POST method. It doesn't work. The SQL is tested and it works. I never use POST method to insert data into a database before. DB is running fine. And the project is on bluemix.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public String addManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer) {

        PreparedStatement query = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        int MANUFACTURERID = 4;
        String MANUFACTURERNAME = "BOOM2";

        // TODO
        try {
            conn = db.DBConn().getConnection();
            String insertQuery = "Insert into MANUFACTURER (MANUFACTURERID,MANUFACTURERNAME) values ('"
                    + MANUFACTURERID + "','" + MANUFACTURERNAME + "')";
            query = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            query.executeQuery();
            query.close();

            // String query=
            // "Insert into users (id,username,password) values('"+id+"','"+Username+"','"+Password+"')";
            // PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(query);
            // stm.executeUpdate(query);
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (conn != null){/*conn.close();*/}
        }
        return "New record inserted";
    }
```

Anything i missed?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: doesn't work .. this is how you define your problem. What you did to debug the issue? Have you tried to log?

Comment: when i type this http://srtwebservice.mybluemix.net/api/test/add in my browser, nothing happened, no error in the runtime log as well

Comment: When you type the url in the browser, you are sending a GET request and not a POST request. Use some tool like RESTclient if you want to test your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a POST method so you must send a HTTP POST request to the server rather than HTTP GET request (putting the URL in a web browser just sends a GET request).

Please look at using something like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) for Chrome or [RestClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) for Firefox to be able to send HTTP POST (and other methods) to your app.

Comment: i use RestClient to test my ws now. it works. Thank you